# Inline out-of-class member function definition

Tags: c++, function, inline, declaration, definition

```
struct S {
    void foo();
};

inline void S::foo() {}
```

Can't figure out from [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) if this function is considered inline or not. We use the `inline` keyword but in the definition of a function previously declared as non-inline. What about the following case?

```
struct S {
    inline void foo();
};

void S::foo() {}
```

Comment: [Associated ruSO question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1406730)